# XAML bind command parameter to DataGrid column name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am using Galasoft MVVM Light. I have a DataGrid with four columns with a gross amount, a VAT-rate, VAT-amount and net amount. When the user changes one of the values then I need to recalculate the other three. I have a relay command attached to the CellEditEnding event of the DataGrid to activate code in the ViewModel that does the calculation. But I need to know which value has been changed in order to do the calculation correctly. How do I specify in XAML which column/cell has triggered the event, i.e. how to bind the command parameter to the name of the triggering column/cell?

```
<DataGrid
     ....>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  CalculateAusgabe_Command, 
                    Mode=OneWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridTextColumn}}, Path=Name}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

In ViewModel the code is:

```
public RelayCommand<string> CalculateAusgabe_Command { get; set; }
...
CalculateAusgabe_Command = new RelayCommand<string>(CalculateAusgabe);
```

and finally the procedure that does the calculation:

```
void CalculateAusgabe(string colName)
{
    if (currBetrag.USt == null) return;
    switch (colName)
    {
        case "colBetBtto":
        case "colBetUStS":
            if (currBetrag.BttoBetrag != 0M)
            {
                currBetrag.UStBetrag = Math.Round((currBetrag.BttoBetrag / (100M + currBetrag.USt.UStProz)) * currBetrag.USt.UStProz, 2);
                currBetrag.NttoBetrag = currBetrag.BttoBetrag - currBetrag.UStBetrag;
            }
            break;
        case "colBetUStB":
        ...
```

The current row of the DataGrid is bound to `currBetrag` object. Everything works fine, `CalculateAusgabe` is activated when the event is triggered but no matter what I do the parameter colName always is null. Any help on this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply perform the calculation in the setters of the currBetrag class? The setter of the property that is shown in the column will be invoked whenever the value is changed and you could then move the CalculateAusgabe method to your currBetrag class and call it in all of these setters. This is the way to solve this using the MVVM pattern. You won't be able use specify a DataGridTextColumn as a RelativeSource as a DataGridColumn is no visual element that gets added to the visual tree.

Comment: Thank you mm8, sounds reasonable. I am have been devoping for many years WinForms applications and now struggling as a newbie with wpf/xaml, so could you please be more detailed? Could you give an short example of these "setters"?

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform the calculations in the setters of the currBetrag class, e.g.:

```
public class currBetrag : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal _bttoBetrag;
    public decimal BttoBetrag
    {
        get { return _bttoBetrag; }
        set
        {
            _bttoBetrag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            CalculateAusgabe("BttoBetrag");
        }
    }

    private decimal _uStBetrag;
    public decimal UStBetrag
    {
        get { return _uStBetrag; }
        set
        {
            _uStBetrag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            CalculateAusgabe("UStBetrag");
        }
    }

    private void CalculateAusgabe(string colName)
    {
        if (USt == null) return;
        switch (colName)
        {
            //set the value of all fields...
            _uStBetrag = ?;
        }

        //and raise the PropertyChanged event for all involved properties
        OnPropertyChanged("UStBetrag");
        OnPropertyChanged("NttoBetrag");
        //...
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
     }
}
```

Note that is considered a bad practice not to use English member names regardless of what your native language is.

Comment: Thank you mm8, now I understand what you meant by "setter": the set part of the object's property. When you mention "...is considered a bad practice..." I would appreciate when you could tell us by whom. I have been told that the biggest cost in the software industry is the part of maintenance so it is extremely important that the maintenance team understands as much as possible and therefore anything apart the programming language should be in local language. To be honest, I understand this argument.

Comment: It is just a general recommendation and pretty much all mainstream libraries and frameworks (such as for example .NET and Java) follow this recommendation. It's not a law though :) Anyway, if your original issue has been solved, please remember to accept the answer and vote it up.

Comment: Well it does not really surprise me when from an English speaking country there is a recommendation to speak English. Apart from that important issue your recommendation is to put business rules / calculations to the Model layer. As I understood MVVM these things belong to ViewModel layer, right?

Comment: I am not from an English speaking country but nevertheless I always use English member names in all of my classes :) And business logic certainly belongs to the model. You don't typically bind directly to POCO business objects in WPF though, instead you wrap the business objects in classes that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise change notifications to the view. The wrapper class is basically a view model.

Comment: OK mm8, it is then probably the age. I am 64 years old, and I have developed in my professional life starting with Asembler and ending with 4G languages. But what I learned to be the most important rule for a developer is to put as much as possible semantics for the poor guys who will have to maintain your code. If unfortunately the programming language is based on English then at least the variables based on business terminology should be in native language.